# Is there a keyboard shortcut for minimizing Mac OS X windows?

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager

Is there a (hidden) keyboard shortcut for minimizing the frontmost window (that works in most apps)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> works in most applications.

Comment: And it's not hidden either.

Comment: Oops.  You're right.  It's right there as the first item in the Window menu.